# How to implement a 'ex :: Maybe [[Maybe a]] -> [[a]] ' method

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement a function of type `Maybe [[Maybe a]] -> [[a]]` in Haskell. I've tried a number of methods, but the closest I have gotten is:

```
ex :: Maybe [[Maybe a]] -> [[a]]
ex list = let l=list!!0 
          in []++(sequence l)
```

That gives me the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[a0]'
                with actual type `Maybe [[Maybe a]]'
    In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `list'
    In the expression: list !! 0
    In an equation for `l': l = list !! 0
```

I know the error has problem with the first argument to `!!` argument not being a normal list, but can't get my head around it.

Comment: Type in question: "Maybe :: [[Maybe a]] -> [[a]]" should be `Maybe [[Maybe a]] -> [[a]]`. Also you can use backticks (`) for inline code.

Comment: How do you want the `ex` function to work? You declare `list` to be a `Maybe [[Maybe a]]` but you are trying to treat it as a list by applying `(!!)`

Comment: Try not to use methods like `(!!)`, `head` or `tail`. Instead pattern match on your arguments. Not only is it good practice, it will also aid you in understanding the problem. You know pattern matching right?

Comment: Check the definition of the `Maybe` type.  Use pattern matching to extract the list and the list entries, but also handle the `Nothing` case.

Comment: I am trying now to pattern match it ! Thanks ! I will get back to this !

Comment: What is it supposed to do? Is `ex ignored = Nothing` any good? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is:

```
ex = maybe [] (map catMaybes)
```

**Approach:**

One way to solve such a problem is to follow the types from the outermost to the innermost, and pick appropriate conversion functions along the way. Here, we will work step by step to modify the expression on the left of the `::` until its type on the right looks like the type you want:

1. We start with `id` as a placeholder for further conversion functions, because it always has the correct type and does nothing:
   `id :: a -> a`
2. Strip off the outer `Maybe`. If the value is `Nothing`, we default to `[]`:
   `maybe [] id :: Maybe [a] -> [a]`
3. We want to convert the inner `[Maybe a]` to `[a]`.
   This can be done with the help of `catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`:
   `maybe [] catMaybes :: Maybe [Maybe a] -> [a]`
4. Actually, we want `[[Maybe a]] -> [[a]]` rather than `[Maybe a] -> [a]`.
    We can use `map :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]` to push a function one level deeper into the list:
   `maybe [] (map catMaybes) :: Maybe [[Maybe a]] -> [[a]]`

**Tools:**

- Use **GHCi** for experimentation. You can ask it for the type of an expression with the `:t` command, for example: `:t maybe [] id`.
- Use API search engines for finding conversions functions. For example [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/) or Hoogle. You can enter a type signature as a search query. For example, `[Maybe a] -> [a]` will return `catMaybes` among others.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the signature `ex :: Maybe [[Maybe a]] -> [[a]]`. The first thing you will want to do is pattern match on the different constructors of your argument:

```
ex :: Maybe [[Maybe a]] -> [[a]]
ex (Just list) = undefined
ex Nothing = undefined
```

So there are two cases we have to handle. For `Nothing` you will most likely just return `[]`. For the `Just` case you will probably want to get out all the `Just` elements in the inner list:

```
ex :: Maybe [[Maybe a]] -> [[a]]
ex (Just list) = catInnerMaybes list
ex Nothing = []

catInnerMaybes :: [[Maybe a]] -> [[a]]
catInnerMaybes (xs:xss) = undefined
catInnerMaybes [] = undefined
```

Again for `catInnerMaybes` we want to pattern match on our argument instead of using methods like `(!!)`. I will leave the rest to you for now but here are some more tips:

- Try to use `:` instead of `++` as it is the more natural, idiomatic way to work with lists and because `++` gets slow quickly.
- I don't think you want `sequence`. You may depending on what exactly you are trying to do, but I think you are more likely to be looking for `catMaybes` in `Data.Maybe`. However I would recommend you don't use that either, but implement it yourself for the learning effect.

Answer (score 0):

[jpath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2246434/jpath) said that you can look for `catMaybes` function but it's better for you to implement by yourself to learn. But if somebody went here not to learn and just to get complete solution then here it is:

```
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)

ex :: [[Maybe a]] -> [[a]]
ex = map catMaybes
```